# Preventing tracking pixels on Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: privacy, email, user-tracking

Is there a way to prevent loading of tracking pixels on Mozilla Thunderbird ? I know there's a way to prevent loading images by default but I'd like to be able to load images without having to worry about being tracked. Basically, I'm looking for some configuration setting (or addon) that gives me the functionality of uBlock Origin on Mozilla Thunderbird.

Comment: If an image (any image) is loaded, and the sender is trying to track their mail, you are being tracked.  No tech restricts tracking to one-pixel images.

Answer (score 6):

Thunderbird on Linux, *I assume Windows is similar*, has 3 viewing settings:

**View**

**Message** **Body** **As**

- Original HTML
- Simple HTML
- Plain Text

**Original** will pull from remote locations to include trackers.

**Simple** will display only embedded content such as attachments or inline pictures.

**Plain** is text only with no HTML processing at all.

Setting to "**Simple**" will eliminate tracker loading as well as all remote loads.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is any intelligent blocking on tracking pixel (Web beacon/webbug) for the most email client.

You can choose to block all the image from loading or not. i.e.

Edit >> Preferences >> Advanced >> Privacy >> Block loading of remote images in mail messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a simple firewall rule to block everything but port 25, 465, 587, 993? I.E:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Thunderbird" dir=out action=block protocol=TCP remoteport=1-24,26-464,466-586,588-992,994-65535 profile=any program="C:\pathToFolder\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

DNS blocking list works to. There i can recomend nextdns.io, is easy to setup and can block trackers.

In my test case: link.getmailspring.com got block by NextDNS Anzeigen & Tracker Blockliste and Steven Black

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).