# Forward messages without tracking pixels using thunderbird

Tags: email, user-tracking, tracking, thunderbird

Thunderbird [does not load remote content by default](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remote-content-in-messages), preventing [pixel-tracking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212687/preventing-tracking-pixels-on-mozilla-thunderbird). However, if I forward an email, the links to remote content is still included in the forwarded email.

**Is there an option in Thunderbird to strip remote content when forwarding an email?**

Comment: Welcome to the community. You always have the option to manually edit the e-mail before forwarding it

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Mmm… I guess so, but if it's a complicated `html` layout with a table and multiple links, it will be a bit complicated / time-consuming to make sure I am not overlooking any image.

Comment: You can search for `img` tags..

Comment: It may not work with emails (I haven't checked), but `img` tags [are not the only way of inserting images](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/afn29t/display_an_image_without_img_tag/): `picture`, `canvas`, `figure` or even css-loaded images can load external content and track as well.

Comment: That was just an example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View -> Message Body As -> Plain Text

Edit -> Account Settings -> Composition & Addressing -> Remove the checkbox for "Compose Message in HTML format"

Now you can forward any message without any tracking content.